# Can I use ZXing-android-embedded for offline product qr code scanning?

Tags: android, zxing

I have a few questions reegarding [ZXing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) made by journeyapps:

- Can the qr code scan function of my app be used offline?
- Do physical product's qr/barcodes require some add-ons?
- Does ZXing's core .jar file have to be installed and put into the
  libs folder?

EDIT: I've come back to this question after a few years, cringed, and realized it can't be deleted. Tried fixing whatever I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes QR Code Scanner can be used offline
2. I think they need hardware to scan (have no much info you can search this part)
3. You can download jar file [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/z/Downloadzxingintegrationjar.htm)